# chart.js custom legend colour based

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, pie-chart

i tried a lot, but nothing has worked for me. I tried to build my own Legend based on the colors in my chart. So for example if my dataset is 1,2,3 and the backgroundcolors in my chart for my data are green,red,red there have to be two legend items. One for the red field with its own name and one for the green field with its own name.

I found this code which was very useful to create a custom legend but this code generates three legend items one for green one for red and another one for red.

Can anyone change the following code that my example is working and that i can give every legend item its own name?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("pieChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;
var theHelp = Chart.helpers;

var data = {
    labels: ["test1 ", "test2", "test3"],
    datasets: [{
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: ['green','red','red'],
        data: [5, 95, 30],
        borderColor: ['green', 'red', 'red'],
        borderWidth: [2, 2, 3]
    }]
};

var options = {
    rotation: -0.7 * Math.PI,
    legend: {
        display: true,
        labels: {
            generateLabels: function (chart) {
                var data = chart.data;
                if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
                    return data.labels.map(function (label, i) {
                        var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
                        var ds = data.datasets[0];
                        var arc = meta.data[i];
                        var custom = arc && arc.custom || {};
                        var getValueAtIndexOrDefault = theHelp.getValueAtIndexOrDefault;
                        var arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;
                        var fill = custom.backgroundColor ? custom.backgroundColor : 
getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.backgroundColor, i, arcOpts.backgroundColor);
                        var stroke = custom.borderColor ? custom.borderColor : 
getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderColor, i, arcOpts.borderColor);
                        var bw = custom.borderWidth ? custom.borderWidth : 
getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderWidth, i, arcOpts.borderWidth);
                        return {
                            text: label,
                            fillStyle: fill,
                            strokeStyle: stroke,
                            lineWidth: bw,
                            hidden: isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
                            index: i
                        };
                    });
                }
                return [];
            }
        }
    }
};

// Chart declaration:
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">

        <canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: deleting the last label isn't working for you or is there some other problem that it causes? `labels: ["test1 ", "test2"],`

Comment: In my case, each data value has its own label and has also its own field in the chart. But if the two values have the same color assigned to them, there should be just one legend item for the red ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. At least not with Chart.JS alone. You need to create a function to summarize the data.

Here is a that which loop into `colors` array. It will find all similar colors and group them together. The labels are also changed to "A & B & C".

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("pieChart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = 'black';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 16;
var theHelp = Chart.helpers;

var globals = {
  labels: ["test1 ", "test2", "test3"],
  colors: ['green', 'red', 'red'],
  data: [5, 95, 30],
}

function groupedData() {
  let obj = {
    labels: [],
    colors: [],
    data: []
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < globals.colors.length; i++) {
    const found = obj.colors.indexOf(globals.colors[i])
    if (found !== -1) {
      obj.labels[found] += " - " + globals.labels[i]
      obj.data[found] += globals.data[i]
      obj.colors[found] = globals.colors[i]
    } else {
      obj.labels.push(globals.labels[i])
      obj.colors.push(globals.colors[i])
      obj.data.push(globals.data[i])
    }
  }

  return obj
}


var data = {
  labels: groupedData().labels,
  datasets: [{
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: groupedData().colors,
    data: groupedData().data,
  }]
};

var options = {
  rotation: -0.7 * Math.PI,
  legend: {
    display: true,
    labels: {
      generateLabels: function(chart) {
        var data = chart.data;
        if (data.labels.length && data.datasets.length) {
          return data.labels.map(function(label, i) {
            var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(0);
            var ds = data.datasets[0];
            var arc = meta.data[i];
            var custom = arc && arc.custom || {};
            var getValueAtIndexOrDefault = theHelp.getValueAtIndexOrDefault;
            var arcOpts = chart.options.elements.arc;
            var fill = custom.backgroundColor ? custom.backgroundColor :
              getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.backgroundColor, i, arcOpts.backgroundColor);
            var stroke = custom.borderColor ? custom.borderColor :
              getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderColor, i, arcOpts.borderColor);
            var bw = custom.borderWidth ? custom.borderWidth :
              getValueAtIndexOrDefault(ds.borderWidth, i, arcOpts.borderWidth);
            return {
              text: label,
              fillStyle: fill,
              strokeStyle: stroke,
              lineWidth: bw,
              hidden: isNaN(ds.data[i]) || meta.data[i].hidden,
              index: i
            };
          });
        }
        return [];
      }
    }
  }
};

// Chart declaration:
var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: data,
  options: options
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">

      <canvas id="pieChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In theorie it is posible to achieve what he wants with a html legend, but its just a lot of work to set it up

Comment: Not exactly what i needed, but you helped me a lot with your code.